# What is the purpose of deleting kwargs in a field's deconstruct method?

Tags: python, django, django-models

With the documentation detailing how to write a custom model field: [Writing custom model fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-model-fields/), I'm failing to understand the implementation of [Field Deconstruction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-model-fields/#field-deconstruction) and the `deconstruct()`.

In the example they provided:

> For example, in our HandField class we’re always forcibly setting max_length in **init**(). The deconstruct() method on the base Field class will see this and try to return it in the keyword arguments; thus, we can drop it from the keyword arguments for readability:

```
from django.db import models

class HandField(models.Field):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 104
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        del kwargs["max_length"]
        return name, path, args, kwargs
```

Reading further down in the documentation it says the following:

> for any configuration of your Field instance, deconstruct() must return arguments that you can pass to **init** to reconstruct that state.

Why is the keyword argument `max_length` being deleted if its required to instantiate the field?

Comment: It sounds like the idea is that since ```max_length``` is always overridden in ```__init__()``` there's no reason for it to be part of the deconstruction that could be used to reconstruct the state of the object. There's no point in saving it if ```__init__()``` is going to ignore it.